# Enumerator as an infinite generator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm reading one resource explaining how Enumerators can be used as generators, which as an example like:

```
triangular_numbers = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  number = 0
  count = 1
  loop do
    number += count
    count += 1
    yielder.yield number
  end
end

print triangular_numbers.next, " " 
print triangular_numbers.next, " " 
print triangular_numbers.next, " "
```

I don't understand the purpose of `yielder` here, what value it takes, and how this code is executing in parallel with the rest of the program's code.

The execution starts at the top, and pauses probably when the block "yields" a value to my code.

Can someone please explain how all this executes in the compiler's eyes?

Comment: +1, good question. Everybody knows that enumerators, when given a block, can yield the enumerations to the block one by one. Basic investigation will tell you, that a newly constructed enumerator creates for itself an instance of `Enumerator::Yielder`. However, the documentation of `Enumerator::Yielder` [is empty](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Yielder.html). It is hard to say what reasons led the designers to delegate the task of yielding (and what else?) from `Enumerator` to `Enumerator::Yielder`. I'm looking forward to the answer.

Comment: @daremarkovic: IIRC, actually, it is **not executing in parallel**. The mechanism underneath is called 'coroutines' and it's "just" a smart orchestration of callbacks/delegates.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: please see the article I've found. I've found it interesting and I think the section about "yielder" explains what you wondered about.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: That's a great article. Good job finding it. But, in your next life, please, choose an easier-to-type name =)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: Thanks! FYI: I've recently found out that there's some TAB-completion on Stack sites :) When you **start** writing the comment with @ then letter, a tooltip with hint shows up and then TAB completes the target username automatically. Unfortunatelly, it seems to work only if @ is the first character of the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've found something that you may find interesting.

This article: ['Ruby 2.0 Works Hard So You Can Be Lazy' by Pat Shaughnessy](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy) explains the ideas behind Eager and Lazy evaluation, and also explains how that relates to the "framework classes" like Enumerale, Generator or Yielder. It is mostly focused on explaining how to achieve LazyEvaluation, but still, it's quite detailed.

---

### Original Source: ['Ruby 2.0 Works Hard So You Can Be Lazy' by Pat Shaughnessy](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy)

> Ruby 2.0 implements lazy evaluation using an object called Enumerator::Lazy. What makes this special is that it plays both roles! It is an enumerator, and also contains a series of Enumerable methods. It calls each to obtain data from an enumeration source, and it yields data to the rest of an enumeration.
> Since Enumerator::Lazy plays both roles, you can chain them up together to produce a single enumeration.
>
> This is the key to lazy evaluation in Ruby. Each value from the data source is yielded to my block, and then the result is immediately passed along down the enumeration chain. This enumeration is not eager – the Enumerator::Lazy#collect method does not collect the values into an array. Instead, each value is passed one at a time along the chain of Enumerator::Lazy objects, via repeated yields. If I had chained together a series of calls to collect or other Enumerator::Lazy methods, each value would be passed along the chain from one of my blocks to the next, one at a time 
> Enumerable#first both starts the iteration by calling each on the lazy enumerators, and ends the iteration by raising an exception when it has enough values. 
> At the end of the day, this is the key idea behind lazy evaluation: the function or method at the end of a calculation chain starts the execution process, and the program’s flow works backwards through the chain of function calls until it obtains just the data inputs it needs. Ruby achieves this using a chain of Enumerator::Lazy objects.

Answer (score 7):

The `Yielder` is just a piece of code that returns the value and wait until the next call.

This can be easily achieve by using the [Ruby `Fiber` Class](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Fiber). See the following example that creates a `SimpleEnumerator` class:

```
class SimpleEnumerator

  def initialize &block
    # creates a new Fiber to be used as an Yielder
    @yielder  = Fiber.new do
      yield Fiber # call the block code. The same as: block.call Fiber
      raise StopIteration # raise an error if there is no more calls
    end
  end

  def next
    # return the value and wait until the next call
    @yielder.resume
  end

end

triangular_numbers = SimpleEnumerator.new do |yielder|
  number  = 0
  count   = 1
  loop do
    number  += count
    count   += 1
    yielder.yield number
  end
end

print triangular_numbers.next, " " 
print triangular_numbers.next, " " 
print triangular_numbers.next, " "
```

I just replaced `Enumerator.new` in your code by `SimpleEnumerator.new` and the results are the same.

There is a "light weight cooperative concurrency"; using the Ruby documentation words, where the programmer schedules what should be done, in other words, the programmer can pause and resume the code block.

Comment: Amazing answer. This answer is so valuable, because it answers the questions even before the original poster realizes ze has to ask them. Thanks for teaching me `Fiber`!

Comment: Cool implementation, but as someone who understands yielders but not Fibers, this is even more confusing.

Comment: @Max The Ruby documentation about Fibers is very clear and easy to understand; that's the reason why I included the link and not tried to explain it in details. The above implementation tries to illustrate what the `Yielder` does behind the scenes, using the Ruby language.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we want to print the first three triangular numbers. A naive implementation would be to use a function:

```
def print_triangular_numbers steps
  number = 0
  count = 1
  steps.times do
    number += count
    count += 1
    print number, " "
  end
end

print_triangular_numbers(3)
```

The disadvantage here is that we're mixing the printing logic with the counting logic. If we don't want to print the numbers, this isn't useful. We can improve this by instead *yielding* the numbers to a block:

```
def triangular_numbers steps
  number = 0
  count = 1
  steps.times do
    number += count
    count += 1
    yield number
  end
end

triangular_numbers(3) { |n| print n, " " }
```

Now suppose we want to print a few triangular numbers, do some other stuff, then continue printing them. Again, a naive solution:

```
def triangular_numbers steps, start = 0
  number = 0
  count = 1
  (steps + start).times do
    number += count
    yield number if count > start
    count += 1
  end
end

triangular_numbers(4) { |n| print n, " " }

# do other stuff

triangular_numbers(3, 4) { |n| print n, " " }
```

This has the disadvantage that every time we want to resume printing triangular numbers, we need to start from scratch. Inefficient! What we need is a way to remember where we left off so that we can resume later. Variables with a proc make an easy solution:

```
number = 0
count = 1
triangular_numbers = proc do |&blk|
  number += count
  count += 1
  blk.call number
end

4.times { triangular_numbers.call { |n| print n, " " } }

# do other stuff

3.times { triangular_numbers.call { |n| print n, " " } }
```

But this is one step forward and two steps back. We can easily resume, but there's no encapsulation of the logic (we could accidentally change `number` and ruin everything!). What we *really* want is an **object** where we can store the state. This is exactly what `Enumerator` is for.

```
triangular_numbers = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  number = 0
  count = 1
  loop do
    number += count
    count += 1
    yielder.yield number
  end
end

4.times { print triangular_numbers.next, " " }

# do other stuff

3.times { print triangular_numbers.next, " " }
```

Since blocks are closures in Ruby, the `loop` remembers the state of `number` and `count` between calls. This is what makes it seem like the enumerator is running in parallel.

Now we get to the yielder. Note that it replaces `blk.call number` from the previous example where we used a proc. `blk.call` worked, but it was inflexible. In Ruby, you don't always have to provide enumerators with blocks. Sometimes you just want to enumerate one step at a time or chain enumerators together, in those cases having your enumerator simply pass a value to a block is inconvenient. `Enumerator` makes enumerators much simpler to write by providing the agnostic `Enumerator::Yielder` interface. When you give a value to the yielder (`yielder.yield number` or `yielder << number`), you're telling the enumerator "Whenever someone asks for the next value (be it in a block, with `next`, `each`, or passed directly to another enumerator), give them this." The `yield` keyword simply wouldn't cut it here because it is *only* for yielding values to blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice concise answer in Ruby Cookbook:

https://books.google.com/books?id=xBmkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT463&lpg=PT463&dq=upgrade+ruby+1.8+generator&source=bl&ots=yyVBoNUhNj&sig=iYXXR_8QqVMasFnS53sbUzGAbTc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fOM-VZb0BoXSsAWulIGIAw&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=upgrade%20ruby%201.8%20generator&f=false

This shows how to make a Ruby 1.8 style `Generator` using the Ruby 2.0+ `Enumerator` class.

```
my_array = ['v1', 'v2']

my_generator = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    index = 0
    loop do
        yielder.yield(my_array[index])
        index += 1
    end
end

my_generator.next    # => 'v1'
my_generator.next    # => 'v2'
my_generator.next    # => nil
```

Comment: how about just yielder.yield(index). Then your example becomes real infinite.

Comment: That would work, if you want an infinite yield.  In my case, I only wanted to go through the items in the array.

Comment: You can test @Lewisou's idea in `irb`: `my_array = ['v1', 'v2'];`
`my_generator = Enumerator.new do |yielder|; index = 0; loop do; yielder.yield(my_array[index]); index += 1; index = 0 if index == 2; end; end;`
`my_generator.next;    # => 'v1'`
`my_generator.next;    # => 'v2'`
`my_generator.next;    # => 'v1'`

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.7 introduced [`Enumerator#produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce) for creating an infinite enumerator from any block, which results in a very elegant, very functional way of implementing the original problem:

```
irb(main):001:0> triangular_numbers = Enumerator.produce([1, 2]) { |(number, count)| [number + count, count + 1] }
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Producer:0x00007f7c69868bd8>:each>
irb(main):002:0> triangular_numbers.first(13).map(&:first)
=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91]
irb(main):003:0> _
```