# Infinite Enumerable

Tags: ruby, hash, generator, enumerator

I'm building a hash with keys available at runtime (so the size of the object isn't known beforehand). I want all these values to be a new instance of a class `ContestStanding`, but not the exact same instance. I've achieved this with

```
h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = ContestStanding.new}
@my_keys.map {|k| h[k]}
h #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding...>, 2=>#<ContestStanding...>, ...}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I could do this using Enums or Lambdas like the following. Note: I've verified this does not work. This is just my thought process

```
Hash[@my_keys.zip(-> { ContestStanding.new })]
```

Here, the problem is my Lambda isn't enumerable. Is there something like an infinite generator in Ruby?

**EDIT**

I initially got really tripped up by that `Enumerable#each_with_object` method. Didn't see the order of `k` and `h` in the block parameters. Thought I was going crazy! As for your suggested implementation, when I run in IRB, this is what I get

```
my_keys = [1,2,3]
my_keys.each_with_object({}) {|k,h| h[k] = 'a'}
#=> {1=>"a", 2=>"a", 3=>"a"}
# The above is what I want to get out of the implementation
Hash[my_keys.zip(Array.new(my_keys.size, Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 'a'}))]
#=> {1=>{}, 2=>{}, 3=>{}}
```

I'm not looking for a Hash of Hashes. That seems to be what the implementation is returning. I'm wanting to get back `{1=>'a', 2=>'a', 3=>'a'}`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Brad, you could use 
`my_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = ContestStanding.new }` where `my_keys.each_with_object({})` is an enumerator.  To use `zip`: `Hash[my_keys.zip(Array.new(my_keys.size, Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]= ContestStanding.new }))]`. Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Comment: For the record, @CarySwoveland's method is the one I would have used, I was more impressed with how you solved the problem, I'd have never thought of that (kinda surprised it works)! the other method is definitely more idiomatic and less confusing though.

Comment: @CarySwoveland See my edit for a couple questions

Comment: Sorry, Brad, I believe that should be `(Array.new(my_keys.size) {ContestStanding.new})`, but I'll check that later this morning.  I'll put it in the form of an answer and also offer some comments on your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad,

Here are two ways you could produce the hash.  I will use the following as an example:

```
class ContestStanding
  def checkit
    puts "hi"
  end
end

my_keys = [1,2,3]
```

**Use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)**

```
h = my_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = ContestStanding.new }
  #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding:0x000001010efdd8>,
  #    2=>#<ContestStanding:0x000001010efdb0>,
  #    3=>#<ContestStanding:0x000001010efd88>}
h[1].checkit #=> "hi"
```

`each_with_object` creates and empty array which is referenced by the block parameter `h`. The first value passed into the block (and assigned to the block parameter `k`) is `my_keys.first => 1`, so have

```
h[1] = ContestStanding.new
```

The other elements of the hash are created similarly.

**Use [Array.zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip)**

```
Hash[my_keys.zip(Array.new(my_keys.size) {ContestStanding.new})]
  #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010280f720>,
  #    2=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010280f6f8>,
  #    3=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010280f6d0>}
```

or, for Ruby v2.0+

```
my_keys.zip(Array.new(my_keys.size) {ContestStanding.new}).to_h
  #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010184bd48>,
  #    2=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010184bd20>,
  #    3=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010184bcf8>}
```

Here the following steps are performed:

```
a = Array.new(my_keys.size) {ContestStanding.new}
  #=> [#<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b248>,
  #    #<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b220>,
  #    #<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b1f8>]
b = my_keys.zip(a)
  #=> [[1, #<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b248>],
  #    [2, #<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b220>],
  #    [3, #<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b1f8>]]
b.to_h
  #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b248>,
  #    2=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b220>,
  #    3=>#<ContestStanding:0x0000010185b1f8>}
```

**Your solution**

I found your solution interesting.  This is one one way of explaining how it works:

```
enum = Enumerator.new { |y| loop { y << ContestStanding.new } }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001011a9530>:each>
a1 = my_keys.size.times.with_object([]) { |k,a| a << enum.next }
  #=> [#<ContestStanding:0x000001018820a0>,
  #    #<ContestStanding:0x00000101882028>,
  #    #<ContestStanding:0x00000101881fb0>
a2 = my_keys.zip(a1)
  #=> [[1, #<ContestStanding:0x000001018820a0>],
  #    [2, #<ContestStanding:0x00000101882028>],
  #    [3, #<ContestStanding:0x00000101881fb0>]]
Hash[a2]
  #=> {1=>#<ContestStanding:0x000001018820a0>,
  #    2=>#<ContestStanding:0x00000101882028>,
  #    3=>#<ContestStanding:0x00000101881fb0>}
```

Comment: Cary, nice explanations! I reasoned my way through `Enumerator#each_with_object` in IRB after the block parameter fiasco was sorted out. I'd never heard of that. That's really cool! My thought process behind using the Enumerator over an Array was I hoped it might be smaller in memory. Say `my_keys` had 1000 elements. I wouldn't be instantiating 1000 ContestStandings in memory all at once, and then immediately copy them to a new data structure. I'd create them once, in the right place. Does that make sense?

Comment: `my_keys.zip` is not an enumerator, so it cannot chain to your  enumerator to create a single enumerator. That means `zip` won't do its thing until its argument is fully built, the same as if its argument were an array.  In any event, `Hash` requires a fully-formed array of tuples to create the hash. That's one advantage of the `each_with_object` approach: no temporary array is needed. By the way, you could instead use `reduce` (aka `inject`), which is what people did before `each_with_object` became available (in v1.9, I believe): `my_keys.reduce({}) { |h,k| h[k] = ContestStanding.new; h }`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for that explanation. If I could ask you one more question, where would you go or what would you do to evaluate performance of function calls like this? To monitor efficiency? Just so I can try to keep myself from continuously posting questions like these in the future

Comment: I think that's mainly just a matter of experience.  If you can think of at least two ways of attacking a problem, it won't be long before you are able to conclude which is best by just thinking them through.  The bigger problem is coming up with option #1, and then option #2. If you have >= 2 options and still are not sure, you could run [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) with some test data.  Search on "Ruby benchmark" and you'll find plenty of examples here.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much for your help. Can't upvote enough.

Answer (score 3):

As I dug through [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html) documentation and [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659326/enumerator-as-an-infinite-generator-in-ruby), I played around with building a custom Enum. I was looking for the nested infinite loop within the Enum block. Final code came out to this

```
Hash[@my_keys.zip(Enumerator.new {|y| loop { y << ContestStanding.new}})]
```

which is pretty darn close to what I wanted!